# geometry question on straight lines

Tags: geometry

Three points X,Y,Z are on a straight line such that XY = 10 and XZ = 3. How can I find the product of all possible values of YZ?

Answer (score 1):

There are only two possibilities, Z-X-Y or X-Z-Y.Then doing the necessary calculations we get YZ either 13 or 7 so answer is 91.

Answer (score -1):

Ths collinearity is X-Z-Y now XY is 10 and XZ is  3 so YZ has to be 7.So proxuct has to be 7. And Z-X-Y so 13 so product =13.7=91

Comment: Why it has to be $XZY$ and $13$ is not allowed?